# Running Node JS server continuously (http-server)

Tags: forever, httpserver

I'm using [ecstatic](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic) as a static file server for my web application, I need to start the project with 'npm start' . As you know there's a way for running nodejs as a daemon which is --Forever . But Forever is suitable for running nodejs scripts not the http-server. I know it may sound silly but I tested 'forever start npm start' and as you may guess it didn't work . Does anybody know the approach for getting this done ?

Comment: Why do you need to run `npm start`? And if you do, why are you running `npm install` instead?

Comment: Sorry it was some kind of syntax error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[forever](https://www.npmjs.org/package/forever) works perfectly fine for HTTP servers. (They’re probably its most common use.) But if you need to start your server using `npm start`, why are you telling forever to run `npm install`?

```
forever start npm start
```

Comment: it gives me this : info:    Forever processing file: npm
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /usr/src/3.14/npm does not exist.

Comment: @user3078441: Try `forever $(which npm) start`, maybe?

Comment: Thanks very much ! it works . `forever start $(which npm) start`

Answer (score 0):

Install forever in your system if it is ubuntu with command npm install forever Then you may proceed like forever start server.js

Answer (score 0):

You should use Node Supervisor. It's really easy and reminds me of shotgun for ruby.

Simple do

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

and then run it using

```
supervisor whateverYourServerIs.js
```

https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor